# Not registerable as an ActiveX component

Tags: ocx

I am receiving an error "The file C:\Windows\SysWOW64\BiPrnDrv.ocx was not registerable as an ActiveX component" when I try to add this component in a VB6 application.

When I try to register this file, I get "The module...failed to load...The specified module could not be found"

What might be the cause of such errors?

Thank you very much...

Comment: The first thing I'd do is [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=biprndrv.ocx) to see if there's official documentation and a support site that might be able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

xSome hints -- that you may have already tested of course :)

1) 32-bits or 64-bits ? Make sure you're using an ocx that your app can handle.

2) Did you look at the logs (event viewer) ?

3) Try to register this ocs with RegSvr32 (regsvr32 [complete filename]). Any error message ?

Cheers.

Comment: "Hints" are usually posted as comments, not answers. Especially ones that you think he may have already tried.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure the part of the question that says "When I try to register..., I get "The module failed to load..." takes care of your #3. This also isn't an answer; it's a list of suggestions of things to try (which you correctly call "hints"). Answers should do just that - answer the question asked. A list of "hints" is not an answer. It's a list of hints.